# Grep the lines without duplicate based on column

Tags: shell

Need your help on this to

I have file like below.

```
04/22/2015 01:00  05/13/2015     8791 16736573  N  Cumulative I 0       0            CAP1    
04/21/2015 01:00  05/12/2015     8762 16733348  N  Cumulative I 0       0            CAP2
04/20/2015 19:25  05/11/2015      421   397297  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2
04/21/2015 20:01  05/12/2015        2      163  N  User Backup  0       0            CAP07_MD_Arch
04/21/2015 20:01  05/12/2015        1     1184  N  User Backup  0       0            CAP07_MD_Arch    
04/21/2015 20:00  05/12/2015        0        0  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2K_M_Arch
04/21/2015 18:00  05/12/2015   293393 48478527  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2K_M_Arch
04/21/2015 21:00  05/12/2015   293393 48478527  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2K_M_Arch
04/21/2015 01:01  05/12/2015     9249 17716144  N  Cumulative I 0       0            CAP05_WP1
04/13/2015 17:26  05/14/2015    63524 36108021  N  Full Backup  0       0            SID20
03/28/2015 12:00  04/28/2015    63491 35996931  N  Full Backup  0       0            SID20
03/21/2015 12:00  04/28/2015    63491 35996931  N  Full Backup  0       0            SID20
```

I have above file with huge list backup image data, my intend is to collect the LATEST successfully "Full Backup" of all clients.

so remove duplicates based on last column and display the latest available backup based on the 1st row ( backup date).

Like below.

```
04/20/2015 19:25  05/11/2015      421   397297  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2
04/21/2015 21:00  05/12/2015   293393 48478527  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP2K_M_Arch
04/13/2015 17:26  05/14/2015    63524 36108021  N  Full Backup  0       0            SID20
```

kindly help us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried so far? See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the input in date order, followed by an awk one-liner:

```
cat INPUT_FILE | sort -t/ -k3.1,3.4 -k1 -k2 |
  awk '/Full Backup/ { backup[$(11)]=$0 } END { for(x in backup) print backup[x] }'
```

Iterates through input, stores latest backup date encountered in an array.

Comment: My first solution was about this simple and easy to read but then I noticed the data didn't appear to be in any logical order.

Comment: Oh, the *input* data.

Comment: Yes, main problem is it's not sorted and, if you _do_ sort it, you need to morph the date so it sorts _properly._

Comment: Fixed by `sort`ing the input in date order.

Comment: where to feed the input file in the pax script, im sorry i tried to give input file on the for id in $(awk '$7=="Full"{print $NF}' INPUT FILE | sort -u); do, but it didnt worked..so can you pls help where to feed the file in that script. sorry for asking silly help as im very new to this...thx

Comment: No problem.  Try this: `cat INPUT_FILE | sort ... | awk ...`.  I edited the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: CAP2KP05 4/18/2015
yes im getting data in close to my intended. thanks alot however can you please help me to get the complete line as like below formatCAP205_WP1 4/20/2015
CAP206 4/18/2015
CAP206_WP2 4/20/2015

Comment: If you want the machine name first, just swap the two items in the print statement.  See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Lars, just i noticed above my comment missed the complete format which im looking for. if i want the complete sentence with all column as like below (you can refer my original post at top)                                                                                              04/20/2015 19:25  05/11/2015      421   397297  N  Full Backup  0       0            CAP205_WP1

Comment: pax im sorry and i almost received my excepted answer on above lars. however could you please tell me where to feed the input file so i can try yours aswell.  Thanks alot Pax & Lars , yours timely help.

Comment: just i tried as like below to get my required coloumns but output comes with no space.                                                                                       bash-3.2$ cat client_list_output2_dup.txt | sort -t/ -k3.1,3.4 -k1 -k2 |awk '/Full Backup/ { backup[$(11)$(7)$(5)$(4)]=$1} END { for(x in backup) print backup[x], x}'                                                                                     
04/21/2015 DB_V_ARCHFull45473885
04/21/2015 CAP210Full3337890860384
04/21/2015 Virt01Full1033908131471
what should i add in above yours command to get the space.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code again.  I hope this is the output format you like.  It should match the output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data doesn't appear to be in date-time order and you're only interested in full backups, some form of filtering and sorting is going to be needed to ensure that the last in the file is *actually* the latest of the correct type. In addition, the sorting is complicated by the American date format rather than something easier to do like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

The following script will do it:

```
pax> for id in $(awk '$7=="Full"{print $NF}' inputFile | sort -u); do
...>     awk -vX=$id '
...>         $NF==X && $7=="Full" {
...>             $1=substr($1,7,4)"-"substr($1,1,2)"-"substr($1,4,2);
...>             print
...>          }' inputFile | sort | tail -1
...>  done

2015-04-13 17:26 05/14/2015 63524 36108021 N Full Backup 0 0 SID20
2015-04-20 19:25 05/11/2015 421 397297 N Full Backup 0 0 CAP2
2015-04-21 21:00 05/12/2015 293393 48478527 N Full Backup 0 0 CAP2K_M_Arch
```

The `for` statement gets a list of *unique* IDs based on the last column of each line, then iterates over those IDs. The `awk` makes sure we only get full backups then prints out the last field on each of those lines, and the `sort -u` removes any duplicates.

The internal line, which runs for each ID, simply grabs all full backup lines where the final column is the currently desired ID value, sorts them so that they're in ascending date/time order, and prints out the last one.